# Problem with sql and sql.connector on python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have recently started working with sql.connector in python and at first everything was fine but now I am having some problems and I don't understand where I am going wrong, this is my code:

```
prova = "4567890"
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql1 = "UPDATE Veicoli SET Presente=1 WHERE Targa = '%s'"
    mycursor.execute(sql1, prova)
    mydb.commit()
    print("  Targa Autorizzata.")
```

I don't understand why once run on python, without errors, it doesn't update the data on the database. Hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: I hope you checked before update that record exists in DB

Comment: Obviously, in fact if I replace "% s" with the content of the test variable, the data is updated in the database, while using "% s" it's not updated

Comment: Remove the quotes around `%s`, because `%s` is the data, not some peace of text put into the string. So your update is done against the string with value `%s`, not the content of variable (I have no MySQL by the hand, but my database throws the error for this `execute(sql1, prova)`: `pyhdb.exceptions.ProgrammingError: Prepared statement parameters expected 0 supplied 1.`

Comment: yes, but if I delete the quotes from %s and add them inside prova, then prova = "'4567890'", sql return error of syntax

Comment: You do not need quotes at all, since your string is already a string. What is the error?

Comment: Because in the sql syntax the content of WHERE must be passed inside the quotation marks, otherwise it is considered INT, right?

Comment: No, because placeholder substitutes *the data*, not some peace of text in query string. It gets the type of passed object, which is mapped to DBMS datatype by driver. So it you pass the string it will become a varchar at DB side, if you pass int - it will be int or something numeric.

Comment: Ah, but if I raise the quotes on sql1 or inside prova, leaving only prova = "456789", sql returns me error: check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '% s' at line 1.

Comment: @Giovanni You may use quotation mark `?` instead, according to examples [here in docs](https://mariadb.com/docs/appdev/connector-python/). I cannot find a good explanation about this part in the documentation, it is very poor and based on a lot of "do like this"

Comment: As [PEP-0249 says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15): *Variables are specified in a database-specific notation (see the module's [paramstyle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) attribute for details).*

Comment: @astentx uh no, using ? I get back a syntax error: check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1. in other sites, however, I had read that the %s had to be put. I thank you all the same for the hand you are giving me :)